# assign function to class method

Tags: php

Is it possible to create a function out of a class method?

ie.

```
class Test {

    public function __construct()
    {
        if ( ! function_exists('foo') ) {
            function foo ()
            {
                 return $this->foo();
            }
        }
    }

    private function foo()
    {
        return 'bar';
    }

}
```

Or would I have to do it the other way around, creating a function and using it within the method?

Comment: `function_exists` will check for global functions, not class methods. Global functions do not have access to `$this`. what are you trying to achieve there? You can create Closures out of Class Methods via http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.getclosure.php

Comment: i'm trying to create a global function that is a copy of the class method. I come from javascript land where functions are just variables and you can easily copy them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it like that, php is able to do it

```
class Test {

    public function __construct()
    {
        if ( ! function_exists('foo') ) {
            function foo ()
            {
                 return $this->foo();
            }
        }
    }

    private function foo()
    {
        outsidefunction();
        return 'bar';
    }

}

private function outsidefunction()
{
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> i'm trying to create a global function that is a copy of the class method. I come from javascript land where functions are just variables and you can easily copy them...

Functions in PHP are not first class citizens, you cannot copy functions around like variables in PHP. You can hand [a *reference* to a function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) around, but not the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you could [use Reflection to get a Closure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php), reference it via `$GLOBALS` and then define a function `foo` to call the [Closure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) from `$GLOBALS`, e.g.

```
<?php // requires 5.4
class Test {

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (!function_exists('foo')) {
            $reflector = new ReflectionMethod(__CLASS__, 'foo');
            $GLOBALS['foo'] = $reflector->getClosure($this);
            function foo() {
                return call_user_func($GLOBALS['foo']);
            }
        }
    }

    private function foo()
    {
        return 'bar';
    }
}

$test = new Test();
echo foo();
```

[Run Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wlx68p)

However, that is extremely ugly and you do not want to do it this way.

If you want more JavaScript like objects, have a look at

- http://www.phpied.com/javascript-style-object-literals-in-php

But still, even the suggested techniques in there are kludges imo.